# "Could not load library: gstreamer" while setting up gstreamer in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gstreamer

I've spent the last couple of hours trying to find an answer to this problem and while I did find some people with a similar problem their solutions didn't work for me.

The steps that I've taken so far:

1.Go to Gstreamer installation page and download the installers for "gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-
1.18.1.msi" and "gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.18.1.msi".
2.Run both installers
3.Open intellij and add the maven dependencies:
[image]
4.Trying to run the cameraTest example and getting the error:
[image]

After that I tried going to the Path variable and adding "%GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86%\bin" (like it is suggested on the installation guide) but the problem remained I even tried -Djava.library.path="D:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin\gstreamer-1.0-0.dll" and still nothing...

Am I missing something obvious? To be honest I'm not that used to working with libraries so I'd appreciate a little help.

Comment: Just the name of the directory containing the library.

Comment: I tried that too but the problem persists, the env vars are set correctly to the ..\bin and I have it in the PATH, even using -Djava doesn't do anything, really don't know what could be the problem

Comment: The library path just contains directories.  Perhaps you change too many things at once?

Answer (score 1):

Try this or place the DLLs in `PATH` environment:

```
-Djava.library.path=D:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/bin
```

`java.library.path` property must point to a directory, not a file.

In IntelliJ IDEA you can also add `D:/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/bin` to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) so that it configures `java.library.path` automatically for you.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, I actually tried a lot of combinations for -Djava (I found some site that said that you could give the direct path to the lib) such as giving it the direct path to a .lib or .dll file or the bin directory and still to no avail...

Comment: I also tried putting the ..\bin in the Path but it didn't work

Comment: Check that the DLL has the same bits architecture as your JDK and that all the dependencies of this DLL are also in the same directory. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (complete zipped project with all the libraries, dependencies and run configurations via Dropbox or you file sharing service of choice).

Comment: I used "java -version" in cmd and it says that it's 64bits, both installers taken from the site have "x86_64" in their titles (which I presume that it means 64 bits, since the rest of the installers had "x86" in their names without "64"), as for the last one the installation guide says:

Comment: "It is the application's responsibility to ensure that, at runtime, GStreamer can access its libraries and plugins. It can be done by adding %GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86%\bin to the PATH environment variable, or by running the application from this same folder." and I have set in env vars the "GSTREAMER_ROOT" as "D:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64" so yeah the dependecies should be all there